# Download files with selenium when get a post with json

Tags: python, json, django, selenium

Hello I want to know that send a json to django url and get link from it. Than send it  via scp. It works when I make as another source file and give a url through argv. But when I put same code into my view.py file, it doesn't work. I don't know what is wrong plz help me

```
import os
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


@csrf_exempt
def download(request):
 message = ((request.body).decode('utf-8'))
 return_json_str = json.loads(message)

 dl_dir = '/home/ubuntu/Downloads'
 url = return_json_str['link']

 display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
 display.start()

 chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

 prefs = {"download.default_directory": '/home/ubuntu/Downloads'}
 chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

 driver.set_window_size(800, 600)
 driver.get('http://login/')
 driver.find_element_by_name('mb_id').send_keys('id')
 driver.find_element_by_name('mb_password').send_keys('passwd')
 driver.find_element_by_class_name('login-button').click()
 driver.get(url)
 time.sleep(1)
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw_basic"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[6]/td/a[1]').click()

 time.sleep(5)
 display.popen.kill()
 driver.quit()

 os.system('scp /home/ubuntu/Downloads/* user@ip.gq:~/Files')
 time.sleep(10)
 os.system('rm /home/ubuntu/Downloads/*')
 return JsonResponse({ })
```